# Should each RDBMS tag have a version number?

Tags: discussion, tagging, allowed-questions, asking-questions

We have RDBMS tags such as `mysql` and `sql-server` but should we only allow tags like this with the version appended? `sql-server-2000` `mysql-5.6`

The reason I bring this up is the features and behavior of these applications change over the years so a correct answer for `sql-server` from a couple of years ago that is high on the google search results may now be lacking details of subsequent additions on the latest versions.

If the answer was for a specific version of the product then it would still be a complete answer in years to come.

Or should we be retrospectively going over old questions about features that have changed and only had a version-less tag to add answers that cover the changes. If so what would be the best way to do this?

An example would be a `sql-server` answer explaining how `sql-server` can update statistics on a partitioned table. The inclusion of incremental statistics adds an extra element to add to any answer from before the release of `sql-server-2014`

Comment: Thanks James - there has been a similar discussion before: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/82/1396. I think we need to keep the top level tag too because it's used for favourites, Google searches and so on.

Comment: OK so would you recommend adding new answers to old questions where updates to the RDBMS in question have caused an old answer to be incomplete?

Comment: Ideally all questions would be tagged with the version the OP is using as wall as the RDBMS, so it wouldn't be an issue - in cases where it isn't, I'm not sure - do you have an example in mind?

Comment: No I was just thinking about how to keep answers at a high quality as the years go by. Didn't consider the SEO side of it though